# Do we have $D^b_{coh}(X)\simeq D^b(coh(X))$ for a compact complex manifold $X$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, derived-categories, triangulated-categories, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold and $\mathcal{O}_X$ be the structure sheaf of holomorphic functions. We call a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$ *coherent* if it satisfies the following two conditions:

1. $\mathcal{F}$ is locally finite generated: For each point $x\in X$ there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a surjective $\mathcal{O}_U$-module morphism  $\mathcal{O}_U^{\oplus n}\twoheadrightarrow \mathcal{F}|_U$;
2. For any open subset $V\subset X$ and any $\mathcal{O}_V$-module morphism $f: \mathcal{O}_V^{\oplus m}\twoheadrightarrow \mathcal{F}|_V$, its kernel $\ker(f)$ is locally finite generated.

Let $D^b_{coh}(X)$ denote the derived category of complexes of sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules with bounded and coherent cohomologies. On the other hand let $D^b(coh(X))$ denote the derived category of bounded complexes of coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules.

In [Generators and representability of functors in commutative and noncommutative geometry](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204218.pdf) Section 5.2 it was written that

> If $X$ is algebraic then it is well-known and easy to prove that
>   $D^b(coh(X))$ and $D^b_{coh}(X)$ are equivalent. We don’t know if the corresponding result is true for the complex analytic case.
>
> > My question is: if $X$ is a compact complex manifold, do we have $D^b_{coh}(X)\simeq D^b(coh(X))$?

Comment: this is a question that I have been thinking about a lot recently. as far as I know, this has been shown to be true only in the case where $X$ is of "low" dimension (I can't remember the reference off the top of my head, but I can find it if you like). I am mildly convinced that the proof of this from SGA 6 (§II, Corollary 2.2.2.1) does not immediately work in the analytic setting, since at some point (in Proposition 2.2.2) they use the fact that a quasi-coherent sheaf is the filtrant colimit of its coherent subsheaves, which is not necessarily true in the analytic setting.